# Configure Webpack to look for files matching directory name

Tags: webpack, development-environment, webpack-loader

I'm setting up an environment for a React app. I'm using Babel and Webpack.

Currently, all of my components are implemented in files following this naming scheme:

```
   /components
          /Component1
                 Component1.js
                 component1.style.scss
                 Component1.test.js
          /Component2
                 Component2.js
                 component2.style.scss
```

Right now, the only two ways I can import these components is to create an `index.js` or `package.json` files, and point them to the Javascript file, or to write the full import; `import Component1 from '/components/Component1/Component1`

Is it possible to configure Webpack so that after looking for `index.js` and `package.json`, it would look for a file that matches the current directory name + `.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't see a way to implement this with current webpack's [`resolve` configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

But here is some [`directory-named-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin) plugin I found which should do exactly what you want.

I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5720) with feature proposal.

Comment: This plugin looks like exactly what I want! Thanks